# Admob red app +18 not in playstore?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

> red app= +18 content app

If I create an Adult Images app and not upload it to Playstore (because its not allowed)
Can Admob knows this apps is a `red app`?

I would upload this app in other page and users could install it from other server (may be from OneDrive)

Yet I haven't built but, this is an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AdMob for that as per Google Policy even though you will upload it in a different server because you still have to comply with Google policy in order to use AdMob.

This issue is related to  [Adult content](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/4410771?hl=en#nudity_and_pornography) or [Prohibited content](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1348688?hl=en#Other_illegal_content).

Publishers are not permitted to place Google ads or AdSense for search (AFS) search boxes on pages with adult or mature content.

In order to use AdMob, publishers must comply with [Google Play Policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113474?hl=en&rd=1).
If you don’t follow the [policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4450958?hl=en), The Google Play Policy team reserves the right to disable your apps if they’re found to violate Google Play policies.

If your account is disabled, you will not be eligible for further participation in AdMob program.

Comment: That is I know, but is there some way they could detect it?